# Why does entering 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD generate ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

When I create table t1 (with c1 being `DOUBLE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`) and try to insert a row as below (**scenario-1**), it generates a `Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '9.223372036854776e18'` warning for c1:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ->  c1 DOUBLE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ->  c2 INT,
  ->  c3 DECIMAL(2) UNSIGNED,
  ->  c4 DECIMAL,
  ->  PRIMARY KEY (c1)
  -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD, 1, -500, "aaa");
Query OK, 1 row affected, 5 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level  | Code | Message                                                    |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'c3' at row 1               |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: 'aaa' for column 'c4' at row 1   |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '9.223372036854776e18' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '9.223372036854776e18' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '9.223372036854776e18' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when we make c1 as `DOUBLE NOT NULL` only (**scenario-2**), it doesn’t generate such warning.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t2 (
  ->  c1 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  ->  c2 INT,
  ->  c3 DECIMAL(2) UNSIGNED,
  ->  c4 DECIMAL,
  ->  PRIMARY KEY (c1)
  -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD, 1, -500, "aaa");
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Level  | Code | Message                                                  |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'c3' at row 1             |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: 'aaa' for column 'c4' at row 1 |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

some context:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%SQL_MODE%";
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| sql_mode      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: How do you plan to increment a double? I suspect adding auto_increment makes mysql make the column some integral type, and then it "helpfully" truncates the non-integral part.

Comment: You are aware that auto_increment works only for integers , int, mediumint ...etc . And that error is thrown because of auto_increment wrong usage on double ?

Comment: In fact in the current version of MySQL, applying the auto-increment option on a float or double column is deprecated, and when you define the table, it warns that you should remove that option from the column.